# Why does python set_index() change index values & column names weirdly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, tuples, multi-index

```
df
            date  outbound   inbound
7     2018-08-10  25.25400  21.98596
8     2018-08-11  24.58363  20.37289
9     2018-08-12  26.88802  23.58856
10    2018-08-13  31.69582  27.84120
11    2018-08-14  26.86707  22.79250
...          ...       ...       ...
1829  2023-08-06  27.42222  17.82758
1830  2023-08-07  28.13449  20.50906
1831  2023-08-08  26.09196  20.19482
1832  2023-08-09  22.92866  17.40861
1833  2023-08-10  23.57808  18.21514

[1827 rows x 3 columns]

df.info()

 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------       --------------  -----  
 0   (date,)      1827 non-null   object 
 1   (outbound,)  1827 non-null   float64
 2   (inbound,)   1827 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(1)
```

This is what my dataframe(df) looks like. I don't know why column names show up with brackets and commas when it doesn't have so in my dataframe.

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df

                outbound     inbound
         date       
(2018-08-10,)   25.25400    21.98596
(2018-08-11,)   24.58363    20.37289
(2018-08-12,)   26.88802    23.58856
(2018-08-13,)   31.69582    27.84120
(2018-08-14,)   26.86707    22.79250
... ... ...
(2023-08-06,)   27.42222    17.82758
(2023-08-07,)   28.13449    20.50906
(2023-08-08,)   26.09196    20.19482
(2023-08-09,)   22.92866    17.40861
(2023-08-10,)   23.57808    18.21514
1827 rows × 2 columns
```

After using set_index() the values of 'date' show up with brackets and commas.

How do I solve this problem?

I'm using python3.8

There doesn't seem to be any way to change all values in and index at once.
I want to write a code that only leaves the numbers and hyphens.

Comment: @Itération122442
I copy and pasted it guess it didn't show up properly. Someone else editted it for me. Can you check it out now?

Comment: what is the output of print(df.columns) ?

Comment: @yashaswik MultiIndex([(    'date',), ('outbound',),( 'inbound',)],)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please convert your columns to regular index by setting your index level to 0 as below :

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```